# How to set PagerTabStrip's text color different when I either choose the page or not

Tags: android, android-viewpager

There is a method called    `setTextColor(),`but it can hardly show different color depend on the state that wheater I choose the page or not.And I want to set the color manually.

Answer (score 1):

in your textview propeties

```
android:textColor="@color/text_selector"
```

in res/color text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="YOUR_CUSTOM_COLOR" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="YOUR_CUSTOM_COLOR" />
    <item android:color="YOUR_CUSTOM_COLOR" />
</selector>
```

Comment: It is common in most textview.However it takes not effect in pagertabstrops.

Comment: than write for them accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you must do is write your color state list:

pager_tab_strip_text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/background_black_3" android:state_window_focused="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/highlight_gold" android:state_window_focused="true" />

</selector>
```

Put your color state list inside a style:

```
<style name="PagerTabStrip">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/pager_tab_strip_text_selector</item>
    </style>
```

The only thing that you must do is, instead of setting this as an style, set it as a textAppearance, like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragment_light_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/fragment_light_pagertabstrip"
            android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStrip.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

This selector should make it happen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For the font selection states to work, a drawable needs to be specified as well 
    (even though it is not used) not sure why.-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Tab is active  -->
    <item   android:state_checked="true" 
            android:color="@color/view_pager_active_tab_color"
            android:drawable="@drawable/my_dummy_drawable" /> 

    <!-- Default -->
    <item   android:color="@color/view_pager_inactive_tab_color" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/my_dummy_drawable" /> 

</selector>
```